# xcode title bar / collection view

Tags: xcode, tabbar, collectionview

probably an easy solution to this, but not sure how.

I'm using colelction view with a tab bar. I'm unable to drag a navigation bar on to the view from the objects pannel, and selecting the navigation bar from the properties pannel works, but doesn't display in simulator mode.

Any thoughts?

Many thanks, again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one way to achieve what you're looking for would be to embed the view controller or collection view controller that contains your collection within a navigation controller (Editor->Embed In>Navigation Controller).

Then instead of linking your controller with your collection directly to your tab bar, you would link the navigation controller that contains it.

Comment: Ah right, yup, well it now shows the title bar, but unable to apply text / buttons. Thoughts ?

Comment: @aaip That's another question entirely, and if this post solved your original problem don't forget to mark as correct :) and you should be able to drag and drop UIBarButtonItems directly to the left/right side of the navigation item (on the view controller), and as far as editing the title goes, this can be done by selecting the navigation item, and then making the changes in the attributes inspector in interface builder. This can all be done in code as well.